# PHP Regex exclude comments finding error suppression

Tags: php, regex, pcre, perldoc

I'm trying to do a regex to look through a pre-existing code base that seems to abuse the hell out of the php error suppression character (`@`) on both variable references and function calls. As a result, I want to search through the entire code base to create a list of all the usages. The problem is, much of the code also include perldoc and I'm not sure how to exclude obvious comments.

most of the perldoc seems to be predicated by a minimum of whitespace-asterix-whitespace. e.g.:

```
  /**
   * @param int $somvar
   */
```

so it could be matched with something like `/^\s*\*\s+/` reasonably consistently.

The regex I'm using to find the usages of the error suppression character (but that grabs the perldoc also) is:

```
/(@[\$\w][\w\d]*)/
```

It's results are satisfactory save for picking up all the perldoc.

I tried looking at some of the examples of negative look-ahead, but don't seem to be evading those perldoc comments with anything I've yet tried. One example of one that doesn't work is as follows:

```
(?!\s*[\*\/])(@[\$\w][\w\d]*)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: unfortunately, some of them are actually used by things - such as doctrine or other interfaces that put their configs in comment blocks with @ symbols

Comment: would not a ?<! be a 'negative look behind'?

Comment: By the way, I tried both negative lookaheads and negative lookbehinds, but they didn't skip the quotes or they ended up skipping too much. Part of the problem is that I specifically need to look for the whitespace-asterix-whitespace at the beginning of the line. Comments after the character won't matter and I don't want to skip lines with multiplication operands either.

Comment: at this point I am just trying to create a list of the uses so we can decide if it's even worth trying to edit some of them out. (some of this codebase has code from an old version of joomla which literally has thousands of them in it!)

Comment: (?<!^\s*[\*\/])(@[\$\w][\w\d]*) is returning an error in one of the test tools I have but runs very slow and still returns perldoc. I also tried it as (@[\$\w][\w\d]*)(?<!^\s*[\*\/]) and it ran normal speed but still returned the perldoc.

Comment: You'd actually need to note the asterisk first in the lookbehind. For skipping multi-line comments just use `(?<![*]\h|[*]\h\h)@..`. You only can't have a quantifier for whitespace there.

Comment: I'm not sure if the \h was a woops, but it's also producing an error. I tested assuming you meant \s - still getting perldoc and I don't think that will exclude specific to the start of line.

Comment: the @$ or @\w can occur anywhere in a line, but I want to ignore any lines that 'begin' with ^\s*\\*\s*

Comment: ok, read up a bit more on the assertions themselves and I think I have a slightly better grasp on it - I got rid of the primary format for the perldoc but have a whole slew of other variants coming in now so I think I'm set. I'm just going to have to include a ton of alternative ignore variations if I can't glob the look behind. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I spoke too soon - getting improved results but I tried this combination: (?<!\s\\*\s|\/\/|\\*\\*|\/\\*)(@[\$\w][\w\d]*) but it is allow a line beginning with " /** @var type " to pass through. It seems to me two conditions should exclude that line - either ** or /* in my 'or' list. (the last two)
Do I need double backslashes in there somewhere?

Comment: lines beginning with /// are slipping through that also despite the second condition

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to find all of the @ symbols instead of regex. This way you're letting PHP's own internal parser parse the file for you:

```
$source_file = 'source_file_to_open.php';
$source = file_get_contents($source_file);
$tokens = token_get_all($source);

// Loop through all the tokens
for ($i=0; $i < count($tokens); $i++) {
    // If the token is equal to @, then get the line number (3rd value in array)
    // of the *following* token because the @ does not have a line number because
    // it's not listed as an array, just a string.
    if ($tokens[$i] == '@') {
        echo "@ found in $source_file on line: {$tokens[$i+1][2]}<br />\n";
    }
}
```